# SNS BARPLOT not displaying data

Tags: seaborn, bar-chart

when I plot the below barplot with out the xlim, the barplot displays the data but when i apply the xlim the data disappears. if i switch the plot to a lineplot, the data re-appears?
\\

```
figs, axus = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1, figsize =(15,5), dpi=1080)

sns.barplot(x= RECAF.index, 
            y='Volume',
            ax = axus,
            data= RECAF, 
            label='Volume',
            color ='k')

#specify 1 year time graph from current date
start = dt.datetime.strptime('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')  
end = dt.datetime.today() 
axus.set_xlim(left= start, right= end)
```

\\

Comment: The bar plot is categorical - look at the dates, they are evenly spaced although the dates on the x-axis are probably not. [See also the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html): This function always treats one of the variables as categorical and draws data at ordinal positions (0, 1, … n) on the relevant axis, even when the data has a numeric or date type.

Comment: If you just want to minimize the margins left and right, you can use `axus.margins(x=0)`.  If you want to limit the range of the plot, it is better to filter it out before the plotting. Something like `filter = (RECAF.index >= start_date) & (RECAF.index <= end_date); sns.barplot(data=RECAF[filter], ...)`.